# Hi I am new to JS and HTML. I am working on below code. I'm trying to create row inside a parent row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent row and child row, I'm able to populate parent and child for 1st parent row but How can I bind using javascript, the parent rows to the 1st parent row if the 3rd and 4th rows are the older rows for the first parent row. the grid preview is shown in the image I have attached.

Javascript for the plus minus function:

```
function divexpandcollapse(div) {
    var div = document.getElementById(div);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + div);

    if (div.style.display == "none") {
         div.style.display = "inline";
         img.src = "Minus-symbol.png";
     } else {
         div.style.display = "none";
         img.src = "Plus-symbol.png";
     }
}
```

Data from my DB:

```
attachment_seq   code    desc    status  replaced_seq
 1  Documents   doc1    active  
 2  SupportDocs doc2    active  
 3  Documents   doc3    expired   1
 4  Documents   doc4    expired   3
 5  Comments    doc5    active
```

[Check The Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fuso.png)

Comment: I can't understand your problem?